# Parents jquery in menu multiple levels

Tags: jquery

Sorry because my English not good! But I have a problem like this.

1. This is my html code (It's a menu multiple level, and levels menu is dynamic)

   ```
   <!-- menu level 1-->
    <ul class='ul_parent'>
      <li>
         <a href='#' class='fNiv'>home</a>
      </li>
      <li>
         <a href='#' class='fNiv'>News</a>
      </li>
      <li>
         <a href='#' class='fNiv'>Product</a>
         <!-- menu level 2-->
         <ul class='ul_childrent'>
           <li>
               <a href='#'>Type 1</a>
               <!-- menu level 3-->
               <ul class='ul_childrent'>
                    <li>
                        <a href='#'>Type 1.1</a>
                        <!--........-->
                        <!-- menu level n-->
                        <!-- ........-->     
                        <ul class='ul_childrent'>
                            <li><a href='#' class='menu_level_n'>Type 1.1...n</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href='#'>Type 1.2</a></li>
                    <li><a href='#'>Type 1.3</a></li> 
               </ul>
          </li>
           <li><a href='#'>Type 2</a></li>
           <li><a href='#'>Type 3</a></li>
         </ul> 
      </li>
    </ul>
   ```
2. I want when click in '`.menu_level_n`' go to set menu level 1 is active (menu class `.fNiv`). This may code jquery (it not work).

   ```
   $(document).ready(function(){
                $('.menu_level_n').click(function(){
                    $(this).parents('.fNiv').addClass('active');
                });
          });
   ```

Please help me! Thanks so murch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the working one

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
         $('.menu_level_n').click(function(){
             $(this).parents('li').last().find('.fNiv').addClass('active');
         });
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

The element with selector `'.fNiv'` is not a parent of your clicked item. You need to find the parent that has an element with this selector as a direct child:

```
$(this).parents().children('.fNiv').last().addClass('active');
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aE9BB/)

Answer (score 0):

change:

```
$(this).parents('.fNiv').addClass('active');
```

to

```
$(this).parents("li").find('.fNiv').addClass('active');
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `eq()` and `siblings()`..

```
 $('.menu_level_n').click(function(){
  $(this).parents().eq(5).siblings('.fNiv').addClass('active');
 });
```

`eq(5)` as your li is 5th level parent and siblings()